# AngularJS - Table from dynamically generated JSON with various key names

Tags: html, angularjs, json, dynamic

I am trying to create a table from dynamically generated JSONs.
For example JSON can look like this:

```
[{"date": "10-10-2010", "Cost":"10", "Column3": 20} ...]
```

But it also can look like this:

```
[{"date": "10-10-2010", "Column1":"ex", "Column2": 1, "Column4": "text"} ...]
```

I want headers of the columns to be names of the JSON keys, and rows cells to be values of those keys. 
Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For header you need to get first row of json data like this:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in jsonData[0]">
       {{header}}
     </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Afterward you should iterate tbody like this:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rowData in jsonData">
      <td ng-repeat="cellData in rowData">
        {{cellData}}
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

This is easiest way to bind dynamic html table.

Hope this will work for you!!

Comment: Works perfect. I did not know that it is possible to loop through object parameters just like elements of array

Answer (score 1):

You need to have array with keys. Let's say we have function that returns keys:

```
$scope.getKeys = function(obj) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).slice(0, -1)
}
```

Now, assuming that in your array of dynamic generated JSONs (let's call it `data`) all objects have the same keys (columns) you can display table as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="key in getKeys(data[0])">
        {{key}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in getKeys(data[0])">{{row[col]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See working snippet with example `data1` and `data2` below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data1 = [{
      "date": "10-10-2010",
      "Column1": "ex",
      "Column2": 1,
      "Column4": "text"
    },
    {
      "date": "11-11-2011",
      "Column1": "ex",
      "Column2": 2,
      "Column4": "text"
    }
  ];

  $scope.data2 = [{
      "date": "10-10-2010",
      "Cost": "10",
      "Column3": 20
    },
    {
      "date": "10-10-2011",
      "Cost": "11",
      "Column3": 30
    }
  ]

  $scope.getKeys = function(obj) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).slice(0, -1)
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <h4>For data1:</h4>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeys(data1[0])">
          {{key}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data1">
        <td ng-repeat="col in getKeys(data1[0])">{{row[col]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h4>For data2:</h4>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeys(data2[0])">
          {{key}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data2">
        <td ng-repeat="col in getKeys(data2[0])">{{row[col]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```